# Is my Relatively Long Solution Correct?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a closed set $F$ and open set $U$ for which $F \subseteq E \subseteq U$ and $m^*(U-F) < \epsilon$, then $E$ is measurable.

Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Then there exist an closed set $F_n$ and open set $U_n$ such that $F_n \subseteq E \subseteq U_n$ with $m^*(U_n - F_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. Then we have $E-F_n \subseteq U_n - F_n$ for every $n$ and therefore $E- \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (E-F_n) \subseteq U_n - F_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (U_n - F_n)$. Therefore by monotonicity we have

$$m^*(E- \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n \le m^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (U_n - F_n)) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(U_n - F_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = \epsilon \to 0,$$

which implies $m^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n) = 0$, where $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ is an $F_\sigma$ set (i.e., countable union of closed sets).

Okay. After having searched the internet for a solution, I now realize that there are considerably simpler solution to the problem. But this leaves me wondering whether my solution is correct; I cannot see anything wrong with it, besides being somewhat longer than the other solutions I found.

Comment: Yes, this proof is correct.